# layers for mesh renderers in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, layer

I'm working in 2D project. I have 2 mesh renderers in unity and I want to set their draw order one above other. But there is no "order in layer" option like sprite renderer has. What can be done to solve this problem ?

I have 3d object which I imporeted into my 2d scene. and also I have object with mesh renderer text. When I move my 3d object closer to camera it can jump over different sprites in the scene so I can put it above all. But when mesh renderer text object appears it tops everything. and it does not metter how I move my 3d object. mesh renderer text object remains on top, even If I see in the editor that it is below.

LAST UPDATE: here in this picture I've added 3d text. default layer in 3d we can see its below, but in game screen u see it's above :(
[image]

[image]
[image][image: This is parameters of text object]

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: updated my question, please have a look

Comment: Check the shader being used by the text renderer.

Comment: added parameters of both objects. sci fi object is 3d object. and text mesh is text

Comment: If you make a new `shader` for your Text or edit your Font Material, you could change the `Render Queue`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set your depth/draw order settings in your camera inspector.
https://answers.unity.com/questions/1208739/how-to-change-draw-order.html
Also create a text gameobject instead of an Ui text

Comment: That's just controlling the draw order of the cameras... not the 'MeshRenderers' [See here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-depth.html)

Comment: I had -1 on my camera depth. I tried to play with it , set different values but nothing happened. Also please read update of my question.

Comment: @David, Problably you have created the text on the UI Layer and it will work at expected

Comment: I think you are right. Its in canvas  But is there way to create it in layer where my 3d object is ? If I manually put it under my 3d object in scene it does not change anything :( probably I must create it somehow differently?

Comment: Yes, create a 3d text( Its similar of creating a cube)  instead of an UI Text . @David

Comment: made 3d text and it's the same as my previous text. it has mesh renderer and text mesh params. And even if I place it below my 3d object it stays above :(

Comment: Change the Layer to default and place it out of the canvas

Comment: Did that but not helped. Check last update with picture please

Comment: Create a children of the spaceship and place the text, it doesnt have any sense to have 2 mesh on the same object

Comment: created child from spaceship, does not help :(